Subsets whose sum is divisible by 5 and orbits of galois field restricted to subgroup
In this 3Blue1Brown video, they use generating functions to count the number of subsets of $\{1,\dots, 2000\}$ whose sum of elements are divisible by $5$. They construct the generating function $F(z) = (1+z)(1+z^2)\dots(1+z^{2000})$, they use a root of unity filter, with $\omega=e^{2i\pi/5}$, to get that this number is $$\frac{1}{5}(F(1)+F(\omega)+F(\omega^2)+F(\omega^3)+F(\omega^4))=\frac{1}{5}(2^{2000}+4\cdot2^{400})$$.
Consider $K=GF(2^{2000})/GF(2)$, and let $\varphi(x)=x^2$, where we note that $\left < \varphi \right > = Gal(K)$. We can find the number of orbits under the action of $\left < \varphi^{400} \right >$ on  $K$ using Burnside's lemma.  The identity fixes the whole field, and each subsequent power of $\varphi^{400}$ will fix a copy of $GF(2^{400})$, so all together, $$|\mathcal{O}|=\frac{1}{5}(2^{2000}+4\cdot2^{400})$$.
I am wondering if there is some "natural" bijection/combinatorial interpretation for this correspondence, as we can certainly think of subsets as binary numbers, but I'm not really sure how to interpret extending the operations of the field to them, or if that is even useful to think about. Is there some connection between subsets whose being divisible by $5$, and the orbits of this automorphism?

I cannot think of any special connection between subsets of $\{1,\dots,2000\}$ whose sum is a multiple of $5$, and elements of $\mathrm{GF}(2^{2000})$. The multiplication structure of $\mathrm{GF}(2^{2000})$ is just too wonky. However, I can give a nice combinatorial proof of why the number of such subsets is equal to $\frac15(2^{2000}+4\cdot 2^{400})$,
I will solve a simpler problem first; proving that the number of subsets of $\{1,2,\dots,5\}$ whose size is divisible by $5$ is equal to $(2^5+4\cdot 2)/5$. Consider the following group action of $\mathbb Z/5\mathbb Z$ on the set of subsets. Define the permutation $\pi$ to map the subset containing $s_1,s_2,\dots,s_k$ ($0\le k\le 5$)  to the subset $(s_1+1),\dots,(s_k+1)$, where the addition wraps around so that $5+1=1$. Since $\pi$ has order $5$, the action generated by $\pi$ is a $\mathbb Z/5\mathbb Z$ action.
I claim that, in each orbit of this action, exactly one subset has a sum which is a multiple of $5$. Two orbits contain a single subset each, the empty set and the full set, and these both have a sum which is a multiple of $5$. For the orbits containing a subset $S$ of size $k$ ($1\le k\le 4$), the sets $S,\pi(S),\pi^2(S),\pi^3(S),\pi^4(S)$ will all have different sums modulo $5$, so exactly one is congruent to $0\pmod 5$, as claimed.
All that remains is to use the lemma-that-is-not-Burnside's to count the number of orbits of this action. The identity permutation has $2^5$ fixed points, while each of the four non-identity permutations has only two fixed points (the empty and full sets). There are no other fixed points because $5$ is prime. Therefore, the number of orbits is $\frac15(2^5+4\cdot 2)$.
Finally, I will modify this method to work for subsets of $\{1,\dots,2000\}$. Note that you cannot just do the same action of $\{s_1,\dots,s_k\}\mapsto\{s_1+1,\dots,s_k+1\}$, because in this case some orbits would have multiple subsets whose sum is a multiple of $5$. Instead, you need to divide $\{1,\dots,2000\}$ into $400$ blocks each with five consecutive integers, $B_1,\dots,B_{400}$. We then define a $(\mathbb Z/5\mathbb Z)$-action as follows:

If $B_1$ is neither empty nor all of $\{1,\dots,5\}$, then use the previous group action on $B_1$ alone, leaving the rest of the subset untouched.

If $B_1$ is empty or full, then try to do the same with $B_2$. For example, if the subset were $\{1,2,3,4,5,\color{blue}{8,10},15,23,1046\}$, then the action on that subset results in $\{1,2,3,4,5,\color{blue}{6,9},15,23,1046\}$.

Continuing in this fashion, you find the smallest number $k$ such that $B_k$ is neither empty nor equal to all of $\{5k-4,5k-3,5k-2,5k-1,5k\}$, and increase all elements of the subset in $B_k$ by one, wrapping around modulo $5$ to stay in $B_k$. If no such $k$ exists, the action does nothing.


With this definition of the group action, the orbits again correspond bijectively to subsets whose sum is a multiple of $5$, so we conclude by counting orbits. This time, the answer is $\frac15(2^{2000}+4\cdot 2^{400})$. To count the fixed points of the four nontrivial permutations, note that a fixed point is one where each $B_k$ is either fully contained or fully excluded from the subset. There are $400$ two-way choices to make, so $2^{400}$ fixed points .

I was mostly interested in seeing how this related to some group action, so this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!
